# How do you iterate actions contained in a actionmanager - Delphi 2007

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, tactionmanager

I am using D2007 for a project that has a number of actions in an actionmanager that are then used in actiontoolbars and menus.  I have also placed them in categories (eg. File, Tools, Input, etc...).  I would like to enable/disable individual actions or a group of actions (eg. input) by iterating a list in actionmanager.  The actions property in actionmanager returns TContainedAction which is not what is needed to complete my task.  Does anyone know where the correct collection is that I need to iterate?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `TContainedAction` does not have `Enabled` property. Try this: `(ActionManager1.Actions[i] as TAction).Enabled := False`